# How to load jedi as installed with el-get?

Tags: emacs, el-get

I have followed the [quick start](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#quick-start) to install jedi. `el-get-list-packages` shows `jedi` as required, but no `jedi` namespace is available, so that I can not run `jedi:install-server`.

How are packages installed with `el-get` loaded? How can I force a load? How do I know where the packages are stored?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jedi doesn't provide any autoloads? In that case you could either provide your own, or just `require` the library outright in your init file.

...but no; looking at the repo your `jedi:install-server` function in `jedi-core.el` has an autoload cookie. el-get ought to have processed that on installation. If you have a `~/.emacs.d/el-get/.loaddefs.el` file, check for the autoload declaration there?

`el-get` presumably still puts things in `~/.emacs.d/el-get/` by default (I use quite an old version, so I'm unsure of what's changed).

n.b. If the `jedi` library is in the `load-path`, then `M-x locate-library RET jedi RET` will tell you where it is located. (And `find-library` can visit it.)